cxf-java2ws-plugin:3.3.13 jd11 is not able to generate wsdl issue in classpath configuration
`complete deppendency is taking for classpath -cp for java2ws command , it should take traget/classes folder as classpath
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-java2ws-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
                        <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
                        <version>6.4.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
                        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-simple</artifactId>
                        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>

                        <configuration>
                            <fork>false</fork>
                            <classpath>/root/test/target/classes/</classpath>
                            <className>com.test.client.Service</className>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java2ws</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
            </plugin>

added this line in configuration of the plugin
/root/cdp/core/mdm-ws-client/target/classes/`

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
